# How to auto insert val after click button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<button type="button" class="all btn btn-xs btn-danger">get all</button>
<br><br>
<tr class="item">
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px 15px 2px 0; ">5000</td>
<td style="padding: 3px 0 0 0;"><button type="button" class="get btn btn-xs btn-danger">get</button></td>
<td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 0; "><input id="mc" name="name['1']" data-max="5000" class="sell">  
</td>
</tr>
<br><br>  
<tr class="item">
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px 15px 2px 0; ">1000</td>
<td style="padding: 3px 0 0 0;"><button type="button" class="get btn btn-xs btn-danger">get</button></td>
<td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 0; "><input id="mc" name="name['2']" data-max="1000" class="sell">  
</td>
</tr>
<br><br>  
<tr class="item">
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px 15px 2px 0; ">8000</td>
<td style="padding: 3px 0 0 0;"><button type="button" class="get btn btn-xs btn-danger">get</button></td>
<td style="padding: 2px 0 2px 0; "><input id="mc" name="name['3']" data-max="8000" class="sell">  
</td>
</tr>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buto').click(function(){
        var value = $("#mc").attr('data-max');
        $("#mc").val(value);
    });
});
```

how to insert amount from data-max to value=(here) after click button (class get)

and 1 button insert into all val from data-max (class all)

Comment: There is no button with class `buto` Should it be `btn` ?

Comment: Also an advise to not use id with the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //for all
  $('.all').click(function(){
    $('input.sell').each(function() {
      var value = $(this).data('max');
      $(this).val(value);
    });
  });
  // and for each
  $('button.get').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var $input  = $parent.find('input:first');
    var value = $input.data('max');
    $input.val(value);
  });
});
```